# cardano-serialization-lib-browser loaded as empty module in NextJS

Tags: cardano-serialization-lib, javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use cardano-serialization-lib in a NextJS project I'm working on, but I'm receiving an exception before initializing the application `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'from_address')` in the following code

```
export const MINTING_POLICY_HASH = () => {
  const vh = Loader.Cardano.EnterpriseAddress.from_address(
    Loader.Cardano.Address.from_bech32(createAccountPolicyBechAddr)
  ).payment_cred()
  // ...
}
```

After digging a little bit, I found out that `Loader.Cardano` was returning a module, but an empty one, `Loader` is defined as follows:

```
class Loader {
  async load() {
    if (this._wasm) return;

    this._wasm = await import(
      "@emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-browser"
    );
  }

  get Cardano() {
    return this._wasm;
  }
}
```

When I tried to print `Loader.Cardano` (after loading it with `Loader.load()` and waiting for it to actually be loaded), it gave me this:

```
Module {
  __esModule: true,
  Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): 'Module'
}
```

Meaning, as I said, the module we are importing (`"@emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-browser"`) is weirdly giving us an empty result. I assume this has to do something with webpack or NextJS and the way they are handling WASM modules, here's my next.config.js:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,

  webpack(config) {
    config.experiments = {
      asyncWebAssembly: true,
      topLevelAwait: true,
    };

    return config;
  },
};
```

I used cardano-serialization-lib twice already with gatsby and create-react-app, but never with NextJS, if anyone could help I would appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know why, but this worked for me

```
this._wasm = await import(
      "../node_modules/@emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-browser/cardano_serialization_lib_bg"
```

:s ES6 notation did not work.

my whole loader:

```
class Loader {
  async load() {
    if (this._wasm) {
      return;
    }
    /**
     * @private
     */
    this._wasm = await import(
      "../node_modules/@emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-browser/cardano_serialization_lib_bg"
    );
  }

  get Cardano() {
    return this._wasm;
  }
}

export default new Loader();
```

Good luck!

Comment: You saved my life, thank you. Spent two days trying to figure out what you did in minutes lol